# Creating a conditional ID field in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a table like this:

| date | userID | accountID | lock/unlock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17/10/2021 | 1 | 1 | unlocked to locked |
| 18/10/2021 | 1 | 1 | locked to unlocked |
| 19/10/2021 | 1 | 1 | unlocked to locked |
| 20/10/2021 | 1 | 1 | locked to unlocked |
| 16/10/2021 | 1 | 2 | unlocked to locked |
| 19/10/2021 | 1 | 3 | unlocked to locked |
| 17/10/2021 | 2 | 1 | unlocked to locked |
| 20/10/2021 | 2 | 1 | locked to unlocked |

I would like to create a new ID field that would only increment for the same combination of userID, accountID and lock/unlock fields. But would reset to 1 whenever a new value combination from those 3 fields come up, like so:

| date | userID | accountID | lock/unlock | newID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17/10/2021 | 1 | 1 | unlocked to locked | 1 |
| 18/10/2021 | 1 | 1 | locked to unlocked | 1 |
| 19/10/2021 | 1 | 1 | unlocked to locked | 2 |
| 20/10/2021 | 1 | 1 | locked to unlocked | 2 |
| 24/10/2021 | 1 | 1 | unlocked to locked | 3 |
| 26/10/2021 | 1 | 1 | locked to unlocked | 3 |
| 16/10/2021 | 1 | 2 | unlocked to locked | 1 |
| 19/10/2021 | 1 | 3 | unlocked to locked | 1 |
| 17/10/2021 | 2 | 1 | unlocked to locked | 1 |
| 20/10/2021 | 2 | 1 | locked to unlocked | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Window` to do something for each partition.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('userID', 'accountID').orderBy('date')

df.withColumn('newID', f.expr("`lock/unlock` = 'locked to unlocked'").cast('int')) \
  .withColumn('newID', f.sum('newID').over(w) + f.lit(1)) \
  .show()

+----------+------+---------+------------------+-----+
|      date|userID|accountID|       lock/unlock|newID|
+----------+------+---------+------------------+-----+
|16/10/2021|     1|        2|unlocked to locked|    1|
|17/10/2021|     1|        1|unlocked to locked|    1|
|18/10/2021|     1|        1|locked to unlocked|    2|
|19/10/2021|     1|        1|unlocked to locked|    2|
|20/10/2021|     1|        1|locked to unlocked|    3|
|19/10/2021|     1|        3|unlocked to locked|    1|
|17/10/2021|     2|        1|unlocked to locked|    1|
|20/10/2021|     2|        1|locked to unlocked|    2|
+----------+------+---------+------------------+-----+
```

Comment: Had to tweak it a bit since lock/unlock is part of the key to determine uniqueness and date was not, but your method worked, thanks!